# Do the Jedi have holidays?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi

Since today is May the 4th, I was wondering if the Jedi Order has any religious holidays. Most religions on Earth have had their fair share of special days/weeks/months, so I imagine the Jedi must also have some days of celebration or reflection. Are there any canon or Legends examples of a special Jedi day/week/month, where Jedi or Force-worshiping laymen do something special for their religion every year?

Maybe a week where they celebrate that one time when they only had enough crystals for one lightsaber, but through their connection with the Force they made it work for eight lightsabers, and then won some space battle? Or even just one day out of the year where they celebrate the discovery of the Force?

I have a bad feeling this has been asked before, but I couldn't find the question.

Comment: Google "Star Wars Holiday Special" and you will have your answer. May the Force be with you, because everyone else will be as far from that s#!t as possible.

Comment: @JohnSensebe was that really a Jedi holiday?  I thought it was a Kashyyyk holiday.

Comment: Well, Leia gives a speech about the meaning of Life Day, and there is apparently a Life Day song that no Wookiee can sing.

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Comment: @RogueJedi Well, I guess I was just hoping for something more satisfying than Jedi celebrating a Christian holiday for no real reason, and then nothing else ever. But I guess since nothing else has come up, yours is a good enough answer.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Thanks. I'll be sure to update it if any other holidays are shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Legends continuity, the Jedi celebrated [Halloween](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Halloween), but it was not their own holiday.

> During the Clone Wars, the Jedi Temple on Coruscant celebrated Halloween at least once. For the festival, carved pumpkins and cobwebs decked the halls. Some pumpkins featured the likenesses of Separatist leader Count Dooku; his enforcer, General Grievous; and his apprentice, Asajj Ventress; others featured the insignia of the Jedi Order. Another decoration featured a B1 battle droid propped up and dressed like a scarecrow. Meanwhile, clone troopers and Jedi Knights wandered about in masks and costumes. Among the masks available to visitors were Senator Padmé Amidala, Grievous, a Gungan, a Hutt, a golden protocol droid, a blue Ortolan, Supreme Chancellor Palpatine, and Jedi Master Yoda. Clone troopers wandered about in shiny, gold armor or were decorated like skeletons that wielded scythes. Jedi Knights dressed in pirate gear. A purple-furred wampa, a pink Tusken Raider, and a green Zillo Beast costume were also available. Even droids dressed up; protocol droids wore masks and fake arms to appear like General Grievous, and astromech droids wore sheets over their domes to appear like ghosts.

[image: Jedi Halloween]

Comment: This is why disney (rightly so) trashed legends.